# RxJava : Start heartbeat after the last emission til the next one arrives

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm working on Http SSE stream and I have to keep the http connexion alive. For that I'm sending an empty message (named heartbeat, all the others are named real events) each 15 second.

```java
source
.map(EventSource.Event::event)
.mergeWith(interval(0, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map(t -> event("").withName("heartbeat")))
```

The drawback of this solution is that I'm sending the heartbeat event if the last real event is sent in < 15 SECONDS.

What I want is start sending the heartbeat events after the last received message is old of 15 SECONDS back, and stop sending this events when getting back the real events.

Something like the following:

> ---x-x-x------x----------x---------------h---------------h---------------h--x---------------h-x----------x---------------h----

- x are real events
- h are heartbeat events
- -  equals to 1 SECOND

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess `switchMap` operator is what you are looking for:

```
source
    .map(EventSource.Event::event)
    .startWith(event("").withName("heartbeat"))
    .switchMap (event -> interval(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .map(t -> event("").withName("heartbeat"))
        .startWith(event)
    )
```

**EDIT**

As you mentioned in comment you need to start heardBeat even if there was no any events yet. For that you need to add some `Init` class into your `EventSource.Event` and use `filter()` operator to ignore it later. See edited code.

**EDIT 2**

removed initialDelay and make it start with HeartBeat event